# How to create a functional Search Bar in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently developing a small Ionic 4 project for college that uses Google Firebase to save and store data, which will be used by the nursing course / class to make things easier for them when it comes to saving patients' data and test details.

In the page that shows all registered patients, I have an **ion-searchbar** which will be used to filter the patients by name and a **ng-container** with a ***ngFor** that pulls all registered patients from the database and puts them into **ion-cards**.

```html
<ion-searchbar placeholder="Search..." expand="full" color="abwb" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ionChange)="search()"></ion-searchbar>

<ng-container *ngFor="let patient of dBase">

    <ion-card color="abwb">
      <ion-card-header style="font-weight: bold">{{patient.name}}</ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/pat-prf', patient.id]" color="bwab">PROFILE<ion-icon name="person" slot="start"></ion-icon></ion-button>
        <ion-button [routerLink]="['/pat-tst', patient.id]" color="bwab">TESTS<ion-icon name="list-box" slot="start"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ng-container>
```

I managed to get the value from what's being typed into the search field to be displayed via a **console.log()** action, but I have no idea on how to make it actually go and search the database for the specified names **OR** to make the **ng-container** only show the cards with names that match.

I've been told I had to use a ***ngIf** to do such a thing, but I honestly got no idea how to use it properly for this kind of thing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions, a Frontend solution and a Backend solution.

**The Frontend solution**

The frontend is to filter out the list that you have from the server. This is can use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). In order to make this work, the backend should return all the patients without pagination (Which can work for small list, but not preferred for big one).

```
// allPatients will contain all the results from the server and dBase will be filtered
private allPatients = [];

ngOnInit() {
   this.httpClient.get(MY_API_TO_GET_PATIENTS)
    .subscribe(response => this.allPatients = this.dBase = response )
}

search() {
  this.dBase = allPatients.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.searchQuery));
}
```

**The Backend solution**

In this solution, we will send a request to the Backend that contains the search query. Then, the Backend will respond with the results that met the search query. Here we will need only to send a new request to the server each time the user enters a new value.

```
search() {
  this.httpClient.get(MY_URL, {params: {searchQuery: this.searchQuery})
    .subscribe(response => this.dBase = response )
}
```

Comment: I tried the Front End solution, but the browser's console gives me a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined at PatientsPage.search (patients.page.ts:33)", line 33 being the action you provided.

Comment: Make sure the the dBase contains the data when you assign the allPatients. I edited the answer to make it clearer

Comment: I decided to try the back-end solution, and the only thing that VSCode seems to be giving me an error in is the line "this.httpClient.get("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com", {params: {searchQuery: this.searchQuery}).subscribe(response => this.dBase[] = response )", asking for a comma just before ".subscribe".

Comment: The code above was for general Restful APIs. You can take a look on this tutorial for Firebase using AngularFire2: https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-6-tutorial-new-features-power For example, instead of the httpClient, you can use ` this.db.list('NAME_OF_LIST').valueChanges().subscribe() ...`